# Is offline_access removed?

Tags: facebook, authentication

If I add permission offline_access to my app, when I try to login it doesn't say that my app wants that permission, or can't be seen in my app settings. Doesn't that work?

I like to make authentication like this:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=182220645211392&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=wap&scope=user_online_presence,friends_online_presence,offline_access,xmpp_login,read_mailbox";

but it doesn't give offline access.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facebook's offline_access has been [deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/).  For now, you can edit your app settings and disable "deprecate offline_access" but it will be removed for good in May.

[image]

Comment: why doesnt my Migrations list look like this? I have like 5 options.. :(

Comment: If you do ask for it on the 3.0.1 SDK, you get a "OrcaServiceQueue(19061): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Cannot provide description for offline_access", the service crashes and the callback is not being called.
Classy.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `offline_access` permission is being removed, you must now:

- Request `access_token` extensions as per this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/
- Handle expired `access_tokens` as per this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/

Comment: It seems that request to extended access token doesn't work at the moment. I'm getting exactly same token back with same expiration.

Comment: I discovered the same bug. You should open a bug with the Facebook dev team.

Comment: @JuusoKosonen Maybe it's because you can extend the expiration time only once per day.

Comment: Seems like there are some other bugs as well. I'm getting Tokens with long expiration time (60 days) but they still expire after ~4 hours (without logging out etc).

Comment: Facebook auth is the most buggy authentication system I've worked with to date. You kind of just have to follow their sparse documentation and hope for the best. It's sad, really.

Comment: Starting the 3.0 SDK, access token extention is handled automatically

Answer (score 0):

currently its deprecated and will be removed by july 5, 2012
http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/