# removing facebook offline access

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing a facebook application.Now as facebook has decided to remove offline access.

I want to know that whether  wp7 facebook c# sdk handles this scenario

Comment: What scenario are you referring to? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084737/is-offline-access-removed

Comment: facebook sdk for android and ios provides long lived token.I want to know whether wp7 facebook c# sdk provides such mechanism.

Comment: @rakeshkumar - Have you checked if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

facebook decided to remove offline access permission that allows to create long lived token. Now this method is depreciated. Now You cant use that permission and your offline access token will not work any more. But alternatively, You can make access token with life of 60 days.

Here is The Documentation on Facebook

[Facebook offline access token documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

You can extend short live access token in this way for 60 days.

```
  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
        client_id=APP_ID&
        client_secret=APP_SECRET&
        grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
        fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

and you can handle your old expired access token by putting try catch block

```
try {
    var client = new FacebookClient("my_access_token");
    dynamic result = client.Get("me/friends");
} catch (FacebookOAuthException) {
    // Our access token is invalid or expired
    // Here we need to do something to handle this.
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: But does facebook c# sdk hadle the this (the question)?

Comment: @Martin: Yes Facebook C# SDK handles that

Comment: Thanks. I've just implemented it myself. For the record I would say the C# SDK does not handle it. The process is very manual and you have to supply everyone of the above fields.